# I'm having a funny problem with my RigidBody

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

I don't know what caused it, but it seems that I cant put an Icosphere (as Active RigidBody) inside an object (as Passive RigidBody) that I tried to put in. It keeps clipping out and does not want to put in. Furthermore, when I tried to add an Location keyframe (for the Passive Object), the Icosphere keeps jumping up instead of staying. I tried seperating the Passive object into individual sides. I've tried to set the collision shape as an Mesh.

Here is the blender file:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/3vyszodszz4w4d8/Test.blend?dl=0

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: Also while files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Answer (score 1):

Hi and welcome to Blender SE,

first of all in rigid body simulations you should apply scale (you had sometimes even negative scale on your objects)

[image]

which Blender's simulation doesn't like. So select all your objects, hit ctrl-a and apply (best: rotation + scale) and then you will get:

[image]

Also it would be great if you could improve your question and tell us what you want to achieve and where your keyframe is? Your text and description should be the same as your blend file if you want good and quick help. What also is a good idea to mention that you are a leaning Blender just for a few days so we know whether the answer can be short and should be longer so you understand how to solve it.

Comment: Ahh, I understand now. Thanks a lot for helping me out! Really appreaciate it

Comment: if my answer helped you, please click on the checkmark left of my answer